# no pandas module for new environment created in Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I tried to create a new environment in Anaconda, if I launch jupyter using this new environment, it will report error on the statement "import pandas as pd"

```
import pandas as pd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

When I goto "environment" menu, check the installed module for this newly created environment, I do find that pandas 0.20.3 has been marked as "installed" . It's weird that if I switch to the root environment (the default environment after installing Anaconda), I'm able to import pandas without any error.  Wondering why it doesn't work for the new environment?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: BTW, I'm able to install pandas using pip in the newly created environment.  Seems the newly created environment doesn't have pandas installed at all, is it a bug in Anaconda Navigator when it shows that pandas is installed already?  And I don't understand why the new env doesn't have pandas installed, I think it should.

Comment: in standard Python we create virtual environment to have Python only with standard modules at start. `pandas` os not standard modules in standard Python. I would expect the same behavior on Anaconda.

Comment: This should not be the case, since Anaconda is python + lots of preinstalled packages including numpy , pandas etc, this is why the root env does include pandas already.

Comment: as I said new environment should have only standard module but `pandas` is not standard module, even if you have it preinstalled with Anaconda, This way you can install different version (ie. older `pandas`) if you need it, and `pip freeze` should show you all modules which you need to deploy project on other computer or server.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I see the reason on why these modules are not installed initially in the new env, but I don't understand on these modules are identified as "installed" for the new Env,  maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I see the reason on why these modules are not installed initially in the new env, but I don't understand on these modules are identified as "installed" for the new Env,  maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, the fix was simple - there is something wrong with the search box in Anaconda's navigator so searching for "pandas" will return no results

Instead, at the top, select "not installed" in the dropdown, then scroll down to pandas in the list instead of searching. Then click the checkbox to enable.